# Chrome Extension + Getting Hang while any dialogue comes while opening a page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, alert

I have created one extension to test my website, which will open page and do some activity like set text, get text etc etc.

I have created one C# application and via websocket I will communicate with extension.

In my extension I have added listener as below,

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    websocket.send(""); // Send signal to C# to execute next command
});
```

so when I will open any website e.g www.google.com, it will fire above event and my next action will come to execute, but issue is while I open any website which will have alert box at the first stage of loading page, will never execute above listener e.g If I will open `http://www.crowderassoc.com/javascript/alertbox.html`, it will give you an alert message, till your click on OK, the page will be busy and so It will get stuck.

I am created automated script, in which I will place one MSAA command to click on that "OK" button, but my it just got hanged.

Is there any option that I can make it work in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Move code of `DOMContentLoaded` Listener

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    websocket.send(""); // Send signal to C# to execute next command
});
```

in `Content Scripts` to listener of [tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) or any of [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html), [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html) Appropriate Listeners in Background Page.

Comment: How to get that page is having alert box or Authentican dialogue box is there? e.g. http://www.tethyssolutions.com/wiki

Comment: @SanketShah: your link is not accesible

Comment: Try this link, http://www.tethyssolutions.com/wiki OR http://www.crowderassoc.com/javascript/alertbox.html